# JavaScript: getElementById - avoiding code duplication

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I've got the following code:

```
 document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea).addEventListener("dragover", 
  function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); }, false);
 document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea).addEventListener("drop",
  this._dropFiles, false);

//SAME CODE, DIFFERENT IDs
  document.getElementById(this.config.dragAreaMobi).addEventListener("dragover", 
       function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); }, false);
  document.getElementById(this.config.dragAreaMobi).addEventListener("drop",
       this._dropFiles, false);
```

If I didn't want to duplicate all this code, what could I do? Is there anyway to do something like `document.getElementsById(var1, var2)` ??
(NOTE: `dragArea = 'id1'` and `dragAreaMobi = 'id2'`).

I tried using jQuery with:

```
 $(this.config.dragArea).bind("dragover", function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

This code didn't work - my best guess is the difference between `bind` and `addEventListner`...
In this instance dragArea was defined as `dragArea = '#id1, #id2'`

Comment: do more ,write less with JQuery

Comment: Would dragArea be `dragArea= 'id1, id2'`? Wouldn't this result in something like `$('#id1, id2)` at runtime? (Second id missing #)

Comment: @user1775598, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function and pass the element to the function

```
function bindEventListeners(elem){
    elem.addEventListener("dragover", function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    elem.addEventListener("drop", this._dropFiles, false);
}

bindEventListeners(document.getElementById(this.config.dragArea));
bindEventListeners(document.getElementById(this.config.dragAreaMobi));
```